# TCL TK checkbutton: get checked button list

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I created a list of check buttons through a for loop.

```
foreach tb $tbs {
    checkbutton .tb_q.q.{$tb} -text $tb -command onClick  \
        -onvalue true -offvalue false -variable selected
}
```

In the proc onClick, I need to figure out which check buttons are checked.

```
proc onClick {} {

    global selected
    
    # Find out all the selected checkboxes index
    ......
}
```

The problem is I cannot set the **-variable selected** here. Because with for loop, every check button will use this variable.

I want to find out the indexes of the checked check buttons. How to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use an array instead of a normal variable, and then iterate over the elements of the array. Demonstration program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env wish

set names {a b c d}
foreach b $names {
    checkbutton .cb_$b -text $b -command onClick -variable selected($b)
    pack .cb_$b
}

button .quit -text Quit -command exit
pack .quit

proc onClick {} {
    global selected
    set chosen {}
    foreach {name val} [array get selected] {
        if {$val} {
            lappend chosen $name
        }
    }
    set chosen [lsort $chosen]
    puts "Selected buttons: $chosen"
}
```